# React native Xcode Bulid error ('Undefined symbol: _$s10ObjectiveC22_convertBoolToObjCBoolyAA0eF0VSbF....etc')

Tags: xcode, react-native

When I try to run the ios simulator with xcode, the build fails

[image]

setting:

macbook air m2
xcode: 14.2

i did try arch -x86_64 yarn ios(in VScode) and BuildSetting Excluded Architectures fixed(in Xcode).

Answer (score 0):

macbook m2 pro
"react-native": "0.65.1"

I had the exact same problem

I was able to run my react-native project without rosetta after doing these steps:

delete: **podfile.lock** 
run: **pod deintegrate** 
run: **pod install**